# Репликация на одном сервере mysql

Tags: mysql

Добрый день! Решил по аналогии с этой статьей http://ruturaj.net/replication-same-server-rewrite-database/ сделать репликацию на одном сервере. Настройки указал такие

```
server-id=1
report-host=master-is-slave-host
log-bin=localhost-binlog
relay-log=localhost-relaylog
replicate-same-server-id=1
binlog-do-db=base1
replicate-rewrite-db=base1->base2
replicate-do-db=base1
replicate-do-table=base1.new_table
```

Команда `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` выдает следующее

```
Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
Master_Host: localhost
Master_User: repl
Master_Port: 3306
Connect_Retry: 60
Master_Log_File: localhost-binlog.000003
Read_Master_Log_Pos: 107
Relay_Log_File: localhost-relaylog.000008
Relay_Log_Pos: 157
Relay_Master_Log_File: localhost-binlog.000003
Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
Replicate_Do_DB: base1
Replicate_Ignore_DB
Replicate_Do_Table: base1.new_table
Replicate_Ignore_Table
Replicate_Wild_Do_Table
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table
Last_Errno: 0
Last_Error
Skip_Counter: 0
Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 4
Relay_Log_Space: 572
Until_Condition: None
Until_Log_File
Until_Log_Pos: 0
Master_SSL_Allowed: No
Master_SSL_CA_File
Master_SSL_CA_Path
Master_SSL_Cert
Master_SSL_Cipher
Master_SSL_Key
Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
Last_IO_Errno: 0
Last_IO_Error
Last_SQL_Errno: 0
Last_SQL_Error
Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids
Master_Server_Id: 1
```

Команда `SHOW MASTER STATUS` выдает

```
File: localhost-binlog.000003
Position: 107
Binlog_Do_DB: base1
Binlog_Ignore_DB
```

Но при изменении данных в таблице из `base1` в `base2` никакие изменения не происходят. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а скажите, зачем это может быть нужно ?

Comment: В моем конкретном случае - исключительно ради любознательности.